# How to Choose an External Regenerative Resistor

Tags: resistors

I have a servo drive that recommends the use of an external regenerative resistor. From what I know, the external regenerative resistor is just a resistor to dissipate power from the servo drive. If 60W 50 ohm resistor is recommended can I use a resistor of lets say 60W 100 ohms?

Comment: I have no idea what an “external regenerative resistor” is, but 60W would be large!

Comment: @user2233709: It's for burning the energy coming from the movement during reversal.

Comment: No, but you can use two 100Ω, 30W resistors and wire them in parallel.

Comment: @Janka that would work. Does the wattage really matter so much as long as the total is above 60W? forgive me I'm not familiar with this stuff.

Comment: You can *always* choose a higher wattage (but it may be more expensive).

Comment: You can always pick resistors which allow more power. That's more a matter of mounting space. The total resistance value in contrary has to match the specs.

Comment: There are basically two choices. Figure out how much power dissipation is required by analyzing the kinetic energy of the system being moved by the servo, or just follow the advice of the supplier. I have seen several drives where a range of resistor values is possible, and you tell the controller what the actual value is. But I would just go with the recommended value.

Answer (score 1):

The more common name of this resistor is **"BRAKING RESISTOR"** , it is commonly used on most AC drives that doesn't support feeding regenerative energy back to the Grid.

As for calculating the power requirement for the resistor is depends on the kinetic energy which is calculated from the mechanical characteristics of the system ( acceleration , deceleration , inertia ..)

There are a lot of resources for example :

[PowerFlex Dynamic Braking Resistor Calculator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbjbj24q_XAhVHShQKHZskAa0QFghEMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fliterature.rockwellautomation.com%2Fidc%2Fgroups%2Fliterature%2Fdocuments%2Fat%2Fpflex-at001_-en-p.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3I-Ij_mONmXR75W0N7iwhL)

[frizlen Online calculator](http://www.frizlen.com/en/service/braking-resistor-calculator/?no_cache=1)

[[PDF]Application Note # 5448 - Galil Motion Control](http://www.galilmc.com/download/application-note/note5448.pdf)

Comment: Yeah, the resistor is by nature NOT regenerative, so "regenerative resistor" is not a good description.

Comment: @JohnD, it is a resistor to prevent overvoltage in a servo drive when in regeneration mode, so I don't think the description is that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is for a braking resistor intended to dissipate the energy from the system taking into account the mechanical inertia.

As such your servo is acting as a generator delivering some number of volts (which you did not mention) and they are recommending 50 ohms at 60W which will establish a braking current of ~1.1A

If you up the resistor to 100R you will drop the braking current to half of that, so your wattage goes down to 30W.

However, the motor will take twice as long to slow down.

Comment: Depending on the decel curve and load, it is possible that drive will trip out on an overvoltage.